# Proof that closure of any set D $in$ R is closed.

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that the closure of any set $D\subseteq \Bbb R$ is closed.

My approach is the following:

We have to show that cl(D) contains all its boundary points, i.e. $bd(cl(D))\subseteq cl(D)$. From basic set theory we know that this means $x\in bd(cl(D))\Rightarrow x \in cl(D)$.
Let $x \in bd(cl(D))$. We have to show that $x\in cl(D)$. Now assume the contrary, $x\notin cl(D)$. Thus, $x\notin (D \cup bd(D))$ and thus $x \notin D$ and $x \notin bd(D)$. It follows that $x \in int(D^c)$.
Since $x \in bd(cl(D))$, for every open ball $B_\epsilon (x)$ it must be that $B_\epsilon (x) \cap cl(D) \neq \emptyset$. It follows that either $B_\epsilon (x) \cap D$ or $B_\epsilon (x) \cap bd(D)$. Since $x \in int(D^c)$, we find an $\epsilon$ where this is not true, a contradiction. Hence, we conclude that $x \in cl(D)$.

I know it seems a bit confusing, but I do not know how i can prove this easier.

Thanks for your comments!
Cheers,
Bernhard

Comment: Isn't one way of defining the closure of a set the following?: The closure of $D$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $D$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield ... So, then, the OP is asking how to prove your definition is equivalent to "contains all its boundary points".

Comment: No.  To show $\mathrm{cl}(D)$ is closed, you don't show $\mathrm{bd}(D)\subseteq \mathrm{cl}(D)$.  You show $\mathrm{bd}(\mathrm{cl}(D))\subseteq \mathrm{cl}(D)$

Comment: It's not immediate that the intersection of an arbitrary collection of closed sets is closed (though that is easy to prove). It depends on what definitions of closure he has to work with.

Comment: @GEdgar you're right, I edited it. It's 3 am here, so I was a bit sloppy while copying from my notes ;)

Comment: I think you can be slightly more direct.  Assume x is a limit point of the closure not in D that isn't a limit point of D.  Then there is a neighborhood of x with no points of D but every smaller neighborhoods have points of D closure the aren't points of D.  These have to be border points.  But every neighborhood of these have points of D.  We can find neighborhoods of the points entirely within the original neighborhood so x *is* limit point of D after all.  So all limit points of D closure are are limit points of D and thus in D closure.  So D closure is closed.